# Public Variable Loses Value When Others Don't Across Modules

Tags: excel, public, vba

I have two modules: `GlobalVariables` and `DoStuff`. Inside the first module, I define several variables that I use as constants throughout the second module. It looks something like:

```
 Option Explicit
 Public VarA As Integer
 Public VarB As Integer
 Public VarC As Integer
 Public VarD As Integer

 Sub Initialize()
     VarA = 30
     VarB = 20
     VarC = 10
     VarD = MyFunction(0)
End Sub
```

Within the second module, I have the following:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function MyFunction(x As Integer)
     MyFunction = 50  'code that gives an integer here
End Function

Sub DoStuff()
     Debug.Print VarA + VarB + VarC + VarD
End Sub
```

The result is 60, instead of the expected 110, because I can see that it views VarD as 0. However, right after running this I can go to the immediate window and type `Debug.Print VarA + VarB + VarC + VarD` and it WILL show me 110.

What is causing this procedure to reset VarD locally only?

Comment: I would recommend using [`Option Explicit`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices) in all modules, compile before running, and if you can post a better example of the `GlobalVariables` module because there is no way to run code outside of a method AFAIK

Comment: I simplified the example to demonstrate the problem. Edited code. Option Explicit is always on, and the `GlobalVariables` just runs through a sub to initialize everything. Of note, I have discovered I can get the correct value by calling the variable `GlobalVariables.VarD` inside the second module, but that is cumbersome and inconvenient. Do you know what I need to do to refer to that variable without a full path name?

Comment: @SandPiper it's really early in the morning, so maybe I'm talking nonsense. Do you always run first `Sub Initialize()` in the first module before running `Sub DoStuff()` in the second module ?

Comment: Yes, the variables are always initialized. All except for the one, VarD, work as expected. I think it has something to do with the fact that VarD was obtained with a function found in that second module, but I can't seem to figure out why that would be or how to get around using the full variable address.

Comment: Why don't you make `MyFunction` a `Sub` and just directly set `VarD`?

Comment: If I run `Initialize` and then run `DoStuff`, it prints 110.

Comment: @YowE3K - same - if I run `Initialize` and then `DoStuff` I get 110

Comment: I have simplified the code behind it. It is actually a more complicated function that is be used by many other subs elsewhere in other modules. I tried changing VarD from Public to Global and that still didn't help. I'll do some more debugging when I get gone later...